# Survive from death by asking the right question twist

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

You are at a path and there is two roads splitting from it. The first one is certain death and the other is the way home. You do not know which way is the right way home, but there are two people.  You can only ask one question.

Now to make this harder from the typical liar-truth teller. You do not know whether they're both liars, both telling the truth, or one of them telling the truth and the other a lie. What do you ask?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Some of the answers to the original question still work here. (Kevin's answer in particular is the canonical solution to this variant; Martin Rattigan's answer also works.)